# Getting name of file and put it in value

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have an issue with duplicate files upload in my website,

However, what I want is while I'm uploading images if there is a duplicate situation the file name will be image1.jpg and if more image2.jpg. I did it at PHP. But I need to get the exact file after uploaded so I can send url to the client correctly.

Here is the code javascript

```
var node = document.getElementById("option-122"),
    ele = document.createElement("form");


ele.className = "fileup"; 

ele.setAttribute("name", "fileToUpload");
ele.setAttribute("id", "fileupload");
ele.setAttribute("method", "post");
ele.setAttribute("target", "hidden-iframe");
ele.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
ele.setAttribute("action", "/wp-content/themes/dalia/upload.php");
node.parentNode.insertBefore(ele, node.nextSibling);

document.getElementById('fileupload').innerHTML = '<input type="file" id="inputfile" name="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadFile()"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="form-submit" style="display: none !important;"><iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>';



document.getElementById('inputfile').onchange = uploadOnChange;

function uploadOnChange() {
  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById('option-122').value = 'www.myurl.com/wp-content/themes/dalia/uploads/'+filename;
  document.getElementById("form-submit").click(); 
}
node.setAttribute("type","hidden");
document.getElementById("fileupload").style.width = '95%';
```

Here is php looks like

```
<?php
  $uploads_dir = 'uploads/';

  $pname = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; 
  $tname=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

  $name = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   $increment = 0; 
   $pname = $name . '.' . $extension;
   while(is_file($uploads_dir.'/'.$pname)) {
     $increment++;
     $pname = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;
   }
   move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.'/'.$pname);
   echo $pname;
?>
```

right now it is all right with writing file name in the value of option-122 but when it is a duplicate situation it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're submitting the form (in an iframe), you can't easily get the new file name. I think you could make your life alot easier and just assign a unique filename at the time of upload using `getTime()`:

All this to your form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='useFileName' value='' />

document.getElementById('fileupload').innerHTML = '<input type="file" id="inputfile" name="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadFile()"><input type='hidden' name='useFileName' value='' /><input type="submit" name="submit" id="form-submit" style="display: none !important;"><iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>';
```

Then set the name in this function

```
function uploadOnChange() {
  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
// get extension
let ext = filename.split(".");
ext = ext[ext.length-1];
let newfile = 'upload-' + new Date().getTime() + "." + ext;
document.querySelector('input[name="useFileName"]').value=newfile;
  document.getElementById('option-122').value = 'www.myurl.com/wp-content/themes/dalia/uploads/'+newfile;
  document.getElementById("form-submit").click(); 
}
```

// then in php, rename the file on upload

```
<?php
  $uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
  $tname=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.'/'.$_POST['useFileName']);
?>
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much but the thing is right now PHP file is not going to upload in a folder can you check again?

Comment: I had a typo on this line, which I just fixed in the answer: `document.querySelector('input[name="useFileName"]').value=newfile;`

Comment: everything working correctly on the javascript side and it is a genius idea, however, on the PHP side still not working. I mean I cannot see the file inside the folder

Comment: If you troubleshoot by print_r($_POST), do you see the right data being passed?

Comment: it says  Array ( [useFileName] => [submit] => Send ) I done it yea :ÇD